# Can you mix Swagger's parameters in query and in body?

Tags: python, swagger, swagger-2.0, connexion

I am getting errors when i am trying it, but i wanted to create an endpoint which accepts 2 query params and 1 body item, a list of names.  When I run it in connexion but says it is an invalid specification.

```
/devices/list:
  post:
    tags: [Devices]
    operationId: app.get_devices
    summary: Gets a complete list of devices.
    parameters:
      - $ref: '#/parameters/foo-t'
      - $ref: '#/parameters/bar-t'
      - in: body
        name: device_names
        required: true
        type: array
        items:
          type: string
        description: a list of devices
...
```

It compiles and runs without the - in: body section.  So i know the 2 parameters are good.  It seems though I am having issue applying sending a json array to python.

Explicitly Returned error is:

> connexion.exceptions.InvalidSpecification: {'in': 'body', 'name':
>   'device_names', 'required': True, 'type': 'array', 'items': {'type':
>   'string'}, 'description': 'A list of Device Names'} is not valid under
>   any of the given schemas
>
> Failed validating 'oneOf' in
>   schema['properties']['paths']['patternProperties']['^/']['properties']['post']['properties']['parameters']['items']:
>       {'oneOf': [{'$ref': '#/definitions/parameter'},
>                  {'$ref': '#/definitions/jsonReference'}]}
>
> On instance['paths']['/devices/list']['post']['parameters'][2]:
>       {'description': 'A list of Device Names',
>        'in': 'body',
>        'items': {'type': 'string'},
>        'name': 'device_names',
>        'required': True,
>        'type': 'array'}

My desired endstate is that I can say:

```
//In javascript
$.post("devices/list", {device_names: ["a","b","c"]}, {params:{foo:1, bar:42}}).success( x => {
  //...
});

# In Python3
def get_devices(foo, bar, device_names):
  pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can mix query and body parameters.

The error is caused by incorrect syntax of the body parameter. Change it so that `type` and `items` are wrapped into `schema`, like this:

```yaml
      - in: body
        name: device_names
        required: true
        schema:   # <-------
          type: array
          items:
            type: string
        description: a list of devices
```

In OpenAPI 2.0, non-body parameters (path, query, header, form params) use the `type` keyword directly, but body parameters must have their type wrapped into `schema`.

The example above matches a request body that contains a string array as is – `["a", "b", "c"]`.

If the array is supposed to be wrapped into a JSON object

```json
{
   "device_names": ["a", "b", "c"]
}
```

you need to change the body parameter as follows:

```yaml
      - in: body
        name: device_names
        required: true
        schema:
          type: object
          required: [device_names]
          properties:
            device_names:
              type: array
              items:
                type: string
        description: a list of devices
```

Comment: The error text does not contain `"schema"` so it appears to match the old definition. Can you double-check that connexion uses the updated definition?

Comment: give me a moment and ill look :)

Comment: it doe look like the type: array is not creating this as valid application/json. It looks looks like it is trying to post line delimited strings.
Is there a swagger way to encapsulate this to be valid json? Example:
`{"device_names":[ "foo", "bar"]}`